# Select Dummy Boolean Column SQL / Access

Tags: sql, ms-access, boolean

Hi I am new to this may I have your help?
months now :) I am trying to select a statement with a dummy boolean column. For example:

```
select ID,Name, FakeColumn as BooleanColumn from Customers
```

How can I achive this ?

I am using microsoft access 2007

I can select a dummy column but it returns to me as a text column type.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Cast the dummy column to a boolean type using [`CBool`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/s2dy91zy.aspx) e.g.

```
SELECT ID, [Name], CBOOL(FakeColumn ) AS BooleanColumn 
  FROM Customers;
```

Comment: hi thank you very much it worked my actual select is select ListID, CBOOL( FALSE ) as MyBoolClmn  from DTCustomer

Comment: but one more question please regarding in this fake boolean. when the access returns the data the column MyBoolClmn is type of boolean but it dosent visualy display it as a checkbox . is this normal?

Comment: @user1166557 I suspect so, since the value is read only. I had a quick Google, a few other people have wondered the same thing. But no solution.

Comment: i research that to but no solution. if any ones know something will be appriciated to share it.

Comment: The nearest you will get, I think, is to set the format to, say, Yes/No.